# Service Client Interface for Simple Dependency Injection?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, mvvm, dependency-injection

I am currently newing up a WCF ServiceClient instance in my ViewModel & directly calling methods exposed by the service for example:

```
private string LoadArticle(string userName)
{
   MyServiceClient msc = new MyServiceClient();
   return msc.GetArticle(userName);
}
```

This is causing tight coupling of ViewModel & Service.I want to use constructor dependency injection, passing in a IMyServiceClient interface thereby allowing me to unit test my ViewModel.

I intend to implement the interface in my ViewModel:

```
public class ArticleViewModel : IServiceClient
{
    private IServiceClient ServiceClient { get; set; }

    public ArticleViewModel(IserviceClient serviceClient)
    {
       this.ServiceClient = serviceClient;
    }
```

I understand how this will work but I am struggling to actually write the interface:

```
Interface IMyServiceClient
{
   // ?
}
```

Can't find an example of this, probably down to incorrect googling.

Ok, here's how I got round this:

The service reference in the client provides an Interface called IServiceChannel which defines a channel for your service. Icreate the channel factory in my first ViewModel that is hit at run time. This instance is then passed through the constructors of the consequent ViewModels throughout the application. I'm simply passing this into my ViewModel constructor  like so:

```
 public ArticleDataGridViewModel(IMyServiceChannel myService)
    {
        this.MyService = myService;

        var factory = new ChannelFactory<IMyServiceChannel>("BasicHttpBinding_IMyService");
        MyService = factory.CreateChannel();
```

The binding details can be found in the app.config.

Comment: just expose the methods you have on your service? ie Article GetArticle(string username)?

Comment: I don't understand that? My methods are implemented in my service, I don't want to implement them in my client app ViewModel, I just want to invoke them?

Comment: You wont implement them again, you will just "proxy" them trough your VIewModel. That is you will expose simialr methods that end up calling the inner service client instance.

Comment: You wont implement them again, you will just "proxy" them trough your VIewModel. That is you will expose simialr methods that end up calling the inner service client instance. I don't think that keeping your service client in the view model is a good idea though, probably better to have it on your controller.

Comment: yes. I think the confusion is you really want to inject your service NOT the wcf service client. so have TWO services both implementing the aame interface. one goes direct to the DB (and is exposed through WCF and one wraps the wcf service client and talks to the first service to get results

Comment: I jist copy the auto generated code into a new class which implements my interface. this also solves problems with object reuse and circular references when you update services etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ViewModel isn't a service, hence it also shouldn't implement `IServiceClient`.

ViewModels prepare data to be displayed in the View and implements presentation logic (what happens when Action A is triggered? Updating of field A, changes value of field B etc. Is textfield C is enabled when A is empty?).

That being said, all you have to do is pass your service into your ViewModel and call it's methods.

```
public class ArticleViewModel : ViewModelBase 
{
    private IServiceClient serviceClient;
    public ArticleViewModel(IServiceClient client) 
    {
        this.serviceClient = client;
    }

    private string LoadArticle(string userName) 
    {
        return this.serviceClient.GetArticle(userName);
    }
}
```

Your ViewModel doesn't need to implement that interface. Just pass it in constructor and hold it into a private field.